# Can't change cursor theme

Tags: mouse, cursor, cursor-theme

I can't change my cursor theme. I downloaded and installed Comixcursor, I have all themes listed in unity tweak tool, but when I select a comix cursor, don't happen anything. Also, when i changed it for redglass the mouse changed, but only if i was pointing in a firefox button/page, very strange. Someone knows what this can be? Thank you.

Comment: I found this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221942)

Comment: i have readed it before, but thank you :)